# Eclipse hot keys don't work in XFCE

Tags: java, eclipse, ide

I'm using a freshly installed Eclipse indigo on my Fedora 16(64bit) with XFCE desktop. But I have only about half of the hot keys working; for example if I try to run my project with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F11</kbd> key nothing happens.

This is true for most combinations, for example, like <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>N</kbd> for starting new projects.

What is a problem? On my previous Ubuntu everything works fine.

Comment: Do all those non-functioning hotkey combinations contain Ctrl ? If so, your System might have registered own hotkeys on combinations with Ctrl and catch those. Just a guess ...

Answer (score 15):

Some, but not all, of the shortcuts are overridden by the Xfce Windows
Manager:

```
Applications->Settings->Settings Manager->Windows Manager
```

then click on the `Keyboard` tab and clear the offending shortcuts.

Answer (score 2):

I've found a workaround! You can fix it by updating file contents of:

```
~/.config/xfce4/xfconf/xfce-perchannel-xml/xfce4-keyboard-shortcuts.xml
```

For the way it worked for me, see: http://peter-butkovic.blogspot.de/2013/02/xfce-changing-standard-global-keyboard.html

I even updated bugzilla report with the relevant information: https://bugzilla.xfce.org/show_bug.cgi?id=9478

Answer (score 2):

For me, it was IBus notification in toolbar which had an option 'Next input method': ctrl+space by default in Xubuntu 14.04.